# How to get an item from a collection in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new to `Laravel` and I cannot figure out how to get the value of an item from within the returned collection. Here is my code:

```
$aircraft = Aircraft::join('pams_shared.shared_aircraft', 'aircraft.shared_aircraft_id', '=', 'pams_shared.shared_aircraft.shared_aircraft_id')
        ->select('aircraft.*', 'shared_aircraft.*')
        ->where('aircraft.owner_id',Auth::user()->owner_id)
        ->where('registration',$reg)
        ->get();
```

I want to get the value from `aircraft.aircraft_id` but that's where I get stuck. I've tried:

```
    $id = $aircraft->aircraft_id;
```

I've tried:

```
    $id = $aircraft->aircraft.aircraft_id;
```

I've also tried:

```
    $id = array_get($aircraft, 'aircraft_id');
```

But I'm getting `null` as a value. When I perform either a `var_dump($aircraft)` or `dd($aircraft)` I'm able to confirm that the data is there.

In my view I am able to access the value by looping through, but I need this data in my controller to perform a second query on another table.

Hope that makes sense. Cheers.

**EDIT**

When running `dd($aircraft);` I get this:

```
Collection {#239 ▼
#items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Aircraft {#240 ▼
            #fillable: array:8 [▶]
            #table: "aircraft"
            #primaryKey: "aircraft_id"
            #connection: null
            #perPage: 15
            +incrementing: true
            +timestamps: true
            #attributes: array:16 [▼
                "aircraft_id" => 5
                "owner_id" => 2
                "shared_aircraft_id" => 67443
                "year" => 2012
                "serial_number" => "C127RG3"
                "registration" => "C-SMTH"
                "created_by" => 2
                "modified_by" => 2
                "created_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                "updated_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                "aircraft_code" => "2072438"
                "aircraft_mfr" => "CESSNA"
                "aircraft_model" => "172RG"
                "aircraft_type" => 4
                "aircraft_eng" => 1
                "aircraft_cat" => 1
                ]
            #original: array:16 [▶]
            #relations: []
            #hidden: []
            #visible: []
            #appends: []
            #guarded: array:1 [▶]
            #dates: []
            #casts: []
            #touches: []
            #observables: []
            #with: []
            #morphClass: null
            +exists: true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: if you are getting `null`, then your query incorrect or you have no values in `db`

Comment: I do get the values when I run `$aircraft` through the `@foreach` loop in my view...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use `get()` method on a `query builder` it would return an array no matter how many record it gets. So you can access it by pointing it by index. By the way do not forget to check for emptiness to overcome possible errors.

```
$id = 0;
$aircraft = Aircraft::join('pams_shared.shared_aircraft', 'aircraft.shared_aircraft_id', '=', 'pams_shared.shared_aircraft.shared_aircraft_id')
        ->select('aircraft.*', 'shared_aircraft.*')
        ->where('aircraft.owner_id',Auth::user()->owner_id)
        ->where('registration',$reg)
        ->get();
// now you can access properties
if(count($aircraft) > 0) $id = $aircraft[0]->aircraft_id;
```

Comment: I get this error: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$aircraft.aircraft_id`

Comment: just as I thought, you dont have that property. Dump the variable and post the result to see.

Comment: The updated answer gives me this error: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$aircraft` I will post my var_dump.

Comment: The updated answer gives me this error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: You should remove the first part and just have the updated answer, as it might be confusing to anyone else looking for the correct answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

If you execute the query with `get()` you will always get a collection as result. Even if you just need one model. The simplest way to change that is to use `first()`:

```
$aircraft = Aircraft::join('pams_shared.shared_aircraft', 'aircraft.shared_aircraft_id', '=', 'pams_shared.shared_aircraft.shared_aircraft_id')
    ->select('aircraft.*', 'shared_aircraft.*')
    ->where('aircraft.owner_id',Auth::user()->owner_id)
    ->where('registration',$reg)
    ->first();

$id = $aircraft->aircraft_id;
```

Comment: I want everything that I'm asking for, I use all of the results in my view, but I want a particular part of the array (`aircraft_id`) to use in my controller before going to my view.

Comment: Do you want one aircraft model or is is possible that the query returns multiple rows?